# how to bind boolean value in angular to the api?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have bind value on option button

```
<select [(ngModel)]="pageInput.isValid">
  <option [value]="true">Valid</option>
  <option [value]="false">Not Valid</option>                            
</select>
```

2nd.html

```
<span [hidden]=""
*ngIf="pageInput.isValid== true" class="color">*</span>
```

when i comparing with this didn't get any change in my result or not showing error, if I comparing value with **'true'** as a string I got result but I need value as a Boolean to the api,
how can Solved this problem??
please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
<option [ngValue]="true">Valid</option>
<option [ngValue]="false">Not-valid</option>
```

and then you can use this:

```
<span [hidden]="" *ngIf="pageInput.isValid" class="color">*</span>
```

and if you want to have the negative one:

```
<span [hidden]="" *ngIf="!pageInput.isValid" class="color">*</span>
```